# Update sqlite database using sqlite-net in windows store app

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

I want to update my database using linq syntax. I have updating in my sqlite database like this

```
 var dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Users.db");
                using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
                {
                     db.Update(new Booking()
                        {
                        });
                        db.Commit();
                        db.Dispose();
                        db.Close();
                }
```

I want to know the update syntax syntax with simple example.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not even attempting to `update`; you're trying to `insert`.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs#L1350) and you'll see that you can just call that instead.

```
var booking = db.Table<Booking>()
                .Where(x => x.Name == "Jack's BBQ joint")
                .FirstOrDefault();
// change something in the object
db.Update(booking);
```

From the docs:

```
/// Updates all of the columns of a table using the specified object
/// except for its primary key.
/// The object is required to have a primary key.
```

An alternative solution is to go lowlevel and create the queries yourself:

```
db.Execute("update bookings set ...");
```

Comment: Yes I knew I just want update syntax which row to be selected how to select that?

Comment: You have to pass in the object that you want to change.

Comment: No it's not because you are creating a *new* `Booking` object. If you want to update a previous record, you first have to get that object from your database, change what you want to change and then just pass it back to `db.Update()`.

Comment: Can u give example of how to get that booking object

Comment: Can i get using linq query like this                                      var d = from x in db.Table<Booking>() where x.name=name select x;

Comment: I updated my post. I used fluent syntax but it is the same as what you wanted. Note that I used `.FirstOrDefault()` because otherwise you'd receive a collection of bookings and you only want one.